# Omit the elements with similar text and leave only one with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <span>USA:</span> Newyork
     <span>USA:</span> Dallas
   </li>
   <li>
     <span>France:</span> Paris
     <span>France:</span> Lyon
     <span>France:</span> Toulouse
   </li>
</ul>
```

Edit:
I want this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <span>USA:</span> 
        Newyork
        Dallas
   </li>
   <li>
     <span>France:</span> 
        Paris
        Lyon
        Toulouse
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to leave only one `USA` and `France` and list their cities below countries.
How can I do this with jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is not completely clear for me what do you want. do you have other countries, or you want only reformat the current ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
$('ul li').each(function(){

    $(this).find('span').filter('span:not(:first)').remove();

});
```

Hope that helps :)

(Bear in mind though, you're not going to have any line breaks, it's going to look a bit compacted when the page is actually rendered in-browser.)